# Bootstrap navbar - align button vertically

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to align a button inside a nav but I can't figure out how to do it. I placed a logo with the height of 50px and aligned other nav items vertically with the line-height property of 50 px. Right now it looks like this:

[image]

When I add a line height to the button as well, the border gets streched out.

Here is my HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img alt="Dolm IT" src="img/logo.svg" height="50px">
                </a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">


                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">showcase</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">our team</a></li>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">get in touch</button>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
```

And here's my CSS:

```
  /*nav*/

    .navbar {
        background-color: transparent;
        border: 0;
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
        color: #01787e;
        font-family: 'Akrobat-ExtraBold';
        font-size: 1rem;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        margin-right: 50px;
    }

    .navbar-nav li a {
        line-height: 50px;
    }


    /*buttons*/

    .btn-default {
        color: #01787e;
        font-family: 'Akrobat-ExtraBold';
        font-size: 1rem;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
    }

    .btn {
        border: 2px solid #01787e;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 7px 30px;
    }
    }
```

[You can see the issue here.](http://dolm.ragne.me/) Thank you for your help.

Comment: Technically only `<li>`s should be direct children of `<ul>`s - have you tried putting the button inside an `<li>`, and maybe putting the line-height declaration on `.navbar-nav li` instead of `.navbar-nav li a`?

Comment: a fiddle or snippet would be immensely helpful.

Comment: Yes, I tried that at some point but it's not working. It lifts the navigation items up and it's not aligned with the logo any more. And since button has its paddings, the rest of the nav is not aligned with it anyway. @jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your `button.navbar-btn` class a `margin-top` of `25px` and you are good to go.

```
button.navbar-btn{
      margin-top:25px
    }
```

Check fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4ku2jhm4/1/

Comment: Works here, but should be 20px;

Comment: That depends upon requirement of user. For some 25px would work and for others 20px. The solution should work and that matters after all. @UltrasoundJelly

Answer (score 0):

Try with this. I did not test it, but it would be something like this.

```
.nuevo{
    width:auto;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:40px;
    padding:5px;
    background:green;
    display:block;
}

     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#">services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">showcase</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">our team</a></li>
                        <li><a class="nuevo">get in touch</a></li>
                    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The top property may be the solution you need here.

```css
.top {
  top: 50px;
}
.lineheight {
  line-height: 50px;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid;
}

li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 5px;
}
```

```html
<button class="top">top</button>
<button class="lineheight">lineheight</button>
<br><br>
<ul class="lineheight">
  <li><a href="#">services</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">showcase</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">our team</a></li>
  <button type="button" class="top">get in touch</button>
</ul>
```